# AppleScript Folder Action - Add Only MP3's from Download folder Automatically to iTunes

Tags: macos, applescript, mp3, itunes

I am trying create an applescript that will automatically add only downloaded MP3's from my download folder as a Folder Action. I found the following script online and it works great except for two things: iTunes launches anytime I download anything from the Internet and also adds pretty much any file that iTunes is willing to add from that download folder. I've tried modifying the code about 15 different times and every time either iTunes does not launch, or iTunes launches for any file downloaded and does not add the file

The original code is:

```
on adding folder items to my_folder after receiving the_files
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in the_files
        tell application "iTunes"
            launch
            try
                set this_file to (item i of the_files)

                add this_file

            end try
        end tell
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you need to use if/then logic to filter for the files you want.  Something along the lines of this (which I did not test, so the syntax may be slightly off)...

```
on adding folder items to my_folder after receiving the_files
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in the_files
        set theCurrentFile to item i of the_files
        if (name extension of (info for theCurrentFile)) = "mp3" then
            tell application "iTunes"
                launch
                try
                    set this_file to (item i of the_files)

                    add this_file

                end try
            end tell
        end if
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

Or, why not use Automator to do this?  It has an action for filtering files and an action for importing files into iTunes.  And, you can create a Folder Action with it. See my attached screenshot.

[image]

Hope this helps.

-Ben

Comment: Thanks man! It worked perfectly. Only mp3's make iTunes open and they are added into iTunes as well. I had tried something similar but it just didn't work correctly. Also, I didn't use automator because I just couldn't get it to do EXACTLY what I wanted it to do. Thanks again for the help.